# Editing ListView's contentY inside it's delegate

Tags: qt, listview, model, qml, delegates

I am trying to change the contentY of customerList inside the **checkB.onClicked** function. However I get the "**ReferenceError: customerList is not defined**" error on the **customerList.contentY=oldY;** line and that line only.

customerList is found in every other line inside that function and they work fine. However, I cannot edit the contentY.

The reason why I am trying to edit the contentY is that when I do customerList.model.select(); the customerList gets updated and gets positioned at the start but I do not want that. How can I fix this?

```
            ListView{
                    id:customerList
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 452
                    Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    clip: true
                    spacing:0

                    model: myListModel
                    delegate: CustomerListDelegate{
                        id:listDelegate
                        checkB.checked: model.checked==="true" ? true : false
                        isCheckAvailable: true
                        width: customerList.width
                        height: 64
                        customerProfileImageSource: imageSource
                        customerName: name
                        customerDate: date
                        customerTotalPd: totalPd
                        customerPanto: panto
                        customerVertex: vertex
                        customerLensType: lensType
                        itemIndex: index

                        checkB.onClicked: {
                            var oldY=customerList.contentY;
                            if(checkB.checked==true)
                                myListModel.checkCustomer(index);
                            else
                                myListModel.uncheckCustomer(index);
                            customerList.model.select();
                            customerList.contentY=oldY;
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: What happens when you delete the line and type it again? (This is to rule out any weird/invisible characters and/or characters that look like alphabet but may be from a different character set).

Comment: When that line is removed there is no errors, everything works normally. There should not be any weird characters, I rewrote it a few times also tried copy pasting from the above line as well.

Answer (score 1):

there may be an issue with accessing the listview by it's id within it's delegate. try to instead use ListView.view.model/contentY instead of  customerList.model/contentY

Read about:
[Attached properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#attached-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the `customerList.model.select();` line? Not sure, what the select() should do here. ListModel does not have a select() method.

I have tried it without this line in a basic ListView and the setting of the contentY value works.